# Chrome cannot find the host entry for website

Tags: dns, hosts

When I try to load a website, I get the following error in Chrome,

```
Chrome could not find img.mzsites.com
```

But on another computer, the site has no problems loading. I have tried `ipconfig /flushdns`, but it does not seem to help.

The following is the output that I got from command line:

```
C:\Users\abcd>nslookup img.mzsites.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    img.mzsites.com
Address:   70.39.xxx.xx


C:\Users\abcd>ping img.mzsites.com
Ping request could not find host img.mzsites.com. Please check the name and try again.
```

Comment: why do nslookup, there is result as "server: unknown"?

Comment: another terrible thing is that I can load the page now, but I bet it will be stop working after a while. This already happened to me a few times since yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely, the owner of the domain transferred the domain to a different DNS server/hosting company, and not enough time has elapsed to allow for proper DNS propagation... or your provider is still caching DNS records that have become stale... or some other combination.  (hence the "non-authoritative answer")  I've done that accidentally myself.

Some additional info about authoritative records can be found here:  http://www.mnet.state.mn.us/data-net/dns/authority.php

I noticed that your DNS server is your router... perhaps your little router is caching the results too.  Try rebooting the device & see if that clears up.